# Auto populate a cell with a date when the refresh button has been selected

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to place a time and date stamp in a cell when the refresh button has been selected.  I've tried a few things online, nothing seems to work.  This is what I am currently using and it just paste some code about embed commandbutton 1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' AutoRefresh all the Tables and Charts
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    If CommandButton1.Select Then
        Range("F8").Value = Format(Date, "dd-mmmm-yyyy") & " " & Format(Now, "h:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems redundant to have the If statement there.  You are already clicking the refresh, so it would appear you want to execute that line.  Take out the If line and the End If line and if should work.

Comment: Thank you, the first time that I did this, I received an error, then I realized that I also need to take out the Then.